# encodedOffset deprecation

Tags: swift, string, nsrange

In my application, I have some code to fetch the range of the host in a `URL`. It looks like this:

```
private func rangeOfHost(text: String) -> NSRange? {
    let url = URL(string: text)
    if let host: String = url?.host {
        if let range = text.range(of: host) {
            return NSRange(
                location: range.lowerBound.encodedOffset,
                length: range.upperBound.encodedOffset - range.lowerBound.encodedOffset
            )
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Xcode has been warning me that `'encodedOffset' is deprecated: encodedOffset has been deprecated as the most common usage is incorrect. Use utf16Offset(in:) to achieve the same behavior.`. However, it's not clear to me how I can replace those encodedOffsets with these suggestions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple and correct way to create an `NSRange` from a `Range<String.Index>` is to use its initializer:

```
public init<R, S>(_ region: R, in target: S) where R : RangeExpression, S : StringProtocol, R.Bound == String.Index
```

In your case:

```
if let range = text.range(of: host) {
    return NSRange(range, in: text)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString1.yourIndex.utf16Offset(in: yourString2)
```

Comment: I've found that for me that the value of yourString2 can be anything at all, and I still get the result I expect.  So I don't understand what that string is for, and I worry that in the future it will suddenly matter and things will break.  The docs, of course, are super helpful: "No description."